# Echo Statement in Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, echo

```
echo. 2>"C:/Users/Documents/test.txt"
```

The above statement creates a empty file called test.txt. 
I want to know usage of 2 in the above statement.

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: ok `2>` redirects stderror only to file, where `1>` will redirect stdout to file only and `2>&1` redirects stderror to stdout so `echo Hello World>file.txt 2>&1` will redirect both stdout and stderror to file... but what do you expect the file to contain? `echo.` will echo only a newline, so you will get an empty file regardless of `>2` redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 in `2>` redirects any error messages to the file you specified. You can test this with something like

```
dir C:\PathThatDoesntExist 2> "C:\Users\Documents\test.txt"
```

View what was written in test.txt with

```
type C:\Users\Documents\test.txt
```

and compare with a path that exists.

```
dir C:\Users\Documents 2> "C:\Users\Documents\test.txt"
type C:\Users\Documents\test.txt
```

So in your particular example with `echo.` (write a new line to the text file) no output is really done to the txt file by the `echo.`. To only write a new line in test.txt (overwriting file if already found) you'd do `echo. > "C:\Users\Documents\test.txt"` or `echo. >> "C:\Users\Documents\test.txt"` to append to an already existing file.